# How to make full-page section boiler plates for article class?

Tags: formatting

I am trying to finish a math-heavy project for college and I need to have 5 sections. I would like to demarcate these sections with full-page, centered headers for each section because I have needed every inch of page space for content up til now. I can't use the \chapter{} header because that only works with the \documentclass{book}, whereas I am using \documentclass{article}.

I am also hoping whoever can help me might have done this already and can share some tips for making this flashy, i.e. centered, framed titles, watermarks, what-have-you. I didn't notice any that were suitable within my programming environment (Overleaf) or I would have just used a template from the start.

Example:

Make this center-page, in large, maybe 32pt font or bigger, maybe with lines above and below it. Or maybe something different. I'm not picky. I just wanted to know how this thing gets enlarged on its own page, primarily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{New Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are not specific enough. You are asking for tips to improve an unknown layout made with unknown fonts and unknown settings and obviously you have only very vage ideas what you want to get in the end.  Shouting at someone who tells you that your question is not answerable won't change this.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I've done a lot of work so far and I am using traditional headers now because I have updated introductory parts that give me more pages to work with. I'll put some code in the OP for you ding-dongs anyway. Then you can all boast about how you would rather do it a completely different way ANYWAY--which would ALSO be great...if I still needed your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible approaches.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage\null\vfil\section{Section Title}\newpage

\lipsum[2]

\clearpage\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
\refstepcounter{section}%
\centering\Large
Section \thesection\\
\Huge\bfseries
Section Title
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\string\numberline{\thesection}Short Title}%
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```